# Java Implementation of LinkedList outputting null

Tags: java, linked-list, null, tostring, singly-linked-list

I'm having a bit of trouble here, I'm implementing my own Linked List class that does what you expect, it adds elements to a list and using a ToString method, outputs them. For some reason, it adds elements to the list fine but when it's time to output the list, it adds a null element to the front and ignores printing the last element. Here is my main class code:

```
public class MyList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(1);                 // [1]
        list.add(2);                 // [1 2]
        list.add(3);                 // [1 2 3]
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

And here's the add and ToString method:

```
public class LinkedList<E>  {
private Node<E> first, last;
private int size = 0;

// new empty list constructor.
public LinkedList() {
    first = last = new Node<>(null, null);
}

public void add(E e) {
    last.next = new Node<>(e, null);
    last = last.next;
    ++size;
}

public void addFirst(E e) {
    Node<E> n = new Node<>(e, null);
    n.next = first.next;
    first = n;
    ++size;

}

public String toString() {
    try {
        if (first != null) {
            Node<E> n = first;
            String s = "[ ";

            while (n.next != null) {
                s = s + n.data + " ";
                n = n.next;
            }

            return s + "]";
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        //return "List is empty!";
    }

    return "List is empty!";
}
```

And when trying to compile the above, I get this output (when it should be `[ 1 2 3 ]`):

```
> [ null 1 2 ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How does your code handle adding the first element in the list?  When you add a node, you're setting `last.next` to the new node, but what is `last` when the list is empty?  Are you perhaps creating an empty node with a `null` data value when you initialize your list?

Comment: I've edited my post and added the code on how I'm creating the first/last node in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
last.next = new Node<>(e, null);
```

*should* throw a `NullPointerException` when you add the first element to the list, because `first` and `last` should be `null` when the list is empty.  The fact that it's apparently not erroring out on you means that `last` must be pointing to a valid `Node` object before you've added anything to your list.  You don't have all of your code in your post, but I'm pretty confident that you're creating a new `Node` and pointing `first` and `last` to it when you call your list's constructor, which means that your list will start with an "empty" node.

What you *should* be doing is starting with both `first` and `last` equal to `null`.  Then do something like this in your `add()` method:

```
public void add(E e) {
    Node newNode = new Node<>(e, null);
    if(first == null) {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    } else {
        last.next = newNode;
        last = last.next;  // Or just last = newNode;
    }
    ++size;
}
```

Also, you need to work on your `toString()` method a bit, because this line:

```
while (n.next != null) {
```

will cause your loop to bypass the last element in the list (since its correct for the list element's `next` to be null).

Comment: Thank you for your help, now it's outputting [ null 1 2 3 ] after making the adjustments to my add and toString method. Hmm...

Comment: Nevermind, what you said about creating a New node and pointing the head and tail to it finally clicked in my head! After some adjustments, it works perfectly. Thank you!